# Characters "ي" and "ی" and the difference in persian - Mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I'm working on a UTF-8 Persian website with integrated mysql database. All the content in the website are imported through an admin panel and it's all persian.

As you might know arabic language has the same letters as persian except some.
The problem is when a person tries to type on a keyboard with arabic layout it writes "ي" as an character and if he tries to type by a keyboard with persian layout it types "ی" as character.

So if a person searches for 'بازی' the mysql won't find 'بازي' as the result.

*Important Note: 'ی' is not the only character with this property, there are lots of them and they are very similar.*

How can I fix this issue?

**One simple naive solution** seems to be replace all  "ي" with "ی" before importing the data into database, but i'm searching for a better robust solution than this.

Comment: This is not unlike "color" vs "colour" in US vs UK english.  It doesn't involve different letters, but the two should be equivalent in searches.  You may want to look for a library that can perform dialect agnostic searches...

Comment: An ideal solution would be to push the search feature up into an indexing engine like Lucene, which would be more flexible in terms of dealing with these kinds of issues, and also - ultimately - faster.  Modifying your actual underlying data to accommodate a search requirement seems like the wrong way to go, but I don't believe that MySQL has the facilities to provide you with a more robust solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Dear EBAG, We have a single **Arabic** block in **Unicode** which contains both Arabic & **Persian** characters.

**06CC** is Persian `ی` and **064A** is Arabic `ي`

Default windows keyboard uses `code page 1256` for arabic characters which put `064A` as default `ي` for bothPersian and Arab users because Arab users are much more than Persian.

`ISIRI` make an standard keyboard `ISIRI 9147` and put both Arabic and Persian `Yeh` on it but Perisan `ی` is the default characters. Persian users which are using standard keyboard will put ( and use ) standard Persian `ی‍ while the rest of them use arabic`ي`.

As you told usually while we are saving a data to database we change arabic `ي` to Persian `‍ی` and when we are reading from it we just go for Persian so everything is true.

the second approach is to use a JavaScript file in web application to control user input. most of the persian websites use this approach to save characters to database. In this method user don't need to install any Keyboard layout for Persian or Arabic keyboard. He/she just put the keyboard on `English` and then in `JavaScript` file developer check that which character is equevalent for him. [Here](http://hasheminezhad.com/kblayout) you can find `ISIRI 9147 javascript` for web application and a Persian Guid to use it.

the Third approach is to use a On-Screen Keyboard that work just like the previous one with a user interface and is usually good for thise who are not familiar with Persian keyboard.

The forth approach is to search both dialect. As you know when you install `MySql` or `SQL Server` you can set the **`collation`** and also you have an option to support dialect ( and case sensivity). if you enable arabic collation with dialect you can get result for both of them and usually this works fine in `sql server` I don't test it in `MySql`. This is the best solution yet.

but if I were you, I implement a simple `sql function` which get `nvarchar` and return `nvarchar`. then I call it when I wanted to write data. and whenever you want to read, you can go for the standard one.

Sorry for the long tail.

Comment: @EBAG, Khahesh Mikonam, If I were you I try Lucene.NET too. it helps you to search with dialect. But I strongly recommend you to integrate your data with replacing arabic `ي` with Persian.

Comment: @NasserHadjloo awesome answer. Just a curiosity: won't fixing it in the webapp with javascript open the door to unchecked inserts of the wrong characters? (e.g. is someone ignores the html site and posts directly). It sounds strange to trust data validation at the client.

Comment: @Miquel Yes you're right. As I mentioned in the last paragraph, `but if I were you, I implement a simple sql function which get nvarchar and return nvarchar. then I call it when I wanted to write data. and whenever you want to read, you can go for the standard one` Just note that It's depend on the situation we're facing.

Answer (score 16):

```
update TABLENAME set COLUMNNAME=REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,NCHAR(1610),NCHAR(1740))
```

or

```
update TABLENAME set COLUMNNAME=REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,'ي',N'ی')
```

Answer (score 4):

This is called a collation. It's what MySQL uses to compare two different characters. I'm afraid I don't know anything about persian or arabic, but the concept is the same. Essentially you've got two characters which map to the same base value. You need to find a collation which maps ي to ی. I'm afraid that's as helpful as I can be without knowing more about the language.

Comment: SHOW COLLATION LIKE 'utf8%' does list utf8_persian_ci as a collation available. That could help.

Comment: @sanmai: at what point did I actually suggest utf8_persian_ci? I said (and I quote): "You need to find a collation which maps ي to ی". That's it. Don't mark me down for your own misunderstanding.

Comment: @isotopp utf8_persian_ci does not help here. You must manually collate.

Answer (score 4):

The first letter (ي) is Yāʾ in the arabic alphabet.
The second letter (ی) is ye in the perso-arabic alphabet.

More on the perso-arabic alphabet here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perso-Arabic_alphabet

"Two dots are removed in the final ye (ی). Arabic differentiates the final yāʾ with the two dots and the alif maqsura (except in Egyptian Arabic), which is written like a final yāʾ without two dots.

Because Persian drops the two dots in the final ye, the alif maqsura cannot be differentiated from the normal final ye. For example, the name Musâ (Moses) is written موسی. In the final letter in Musâ, Persian does not differentiate between ye or an alif maqsura."

Seems to be an interesting problem...

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the similar situation 5-6 years ago, when Lucene was not an option for MySQL and there were no Sphinx (Never tried Sphinx result on this), but what I did was I found  pretty much most of the possible alternations and put them in an array in PHP.
So if the input keyword contained any of those characters, I generated all the possible alternates of that.

So for the input of  'بازی' I would have generated  {'بازي' , 'بازی' } and then I would query the MySQL for both, like the simplest query below :

```
SELECT title,Describtion FROM Games WHERE Description LIKE '%بازي%' OR Description LIKE '%بازی%'
```

The primary list of alternatives is not very long though.

Comment: I was just curious and tried different options with MySQL FULLTEXT search and different collations ("utf8_bin", "utf8_persian_ci" , "utf8_general_ci"), and it was interesting to see when you store the values in the unicode format in DB (&#1576;&#1575;&#1586;&#1740;) it would easily search and treat ی and ي the same way (Worked for all the collations mentioned above). As long as you do a "MATCH(field) AGAINST". 
It's just a matter of the size of data which is stored.

Answer (score 2):

If you've the possibility to switch DB engine, you might want to look into the full text search functionality of PostgreSQL:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html

Among other things, you can configure it so that it indexes/searches unaccented characters, and you can define all sorts of additional dictionaries (e.g. stop words, thesaurus, synonyms, etc.).

If not, consider using [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) instead of `like` statements for your searches.

Comment: The question is specifically about MySQL.

Comment: @Sanmai: And that's precisely why I started with "If you've the possibility to switch DB engine". Because the OP has no solution to speak of for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I know answering this topic is like digging a corpse from its grave since it's really old but I'd like to share my experience IMHO, the best way is to wrap your request and apply your replacement . it's more portable than other ways. here is a java sample

```
public class FarsiRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{

@Override
public String getParameter(String name) {
    String parameterValue = super.getParameter(name);
    parameterValue.replace("ی", "ي");       
    parameterValue.replace("\\s+", " ");
    parameterValue.replace("ک","ک");
    return parameter.trim();
}
```

}

then you only need to setup a filter servlet

```
public class FarsiFilter implements Filter{

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    FarsiRequestWrapper rw = new FarsiRequestWrapper(req);
    chain.doFilter(rw, response);
}
```

}
although this approach only works in Java, I found it simpler and better.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **N** (meaning uNicode) before non-English characters, for example:

`REPLACE(COLUMNNAME, N'ي', N'ی')`