# 'ی' and 'ک' are not searchable in main memory

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, utf, unicode-literals

I have a data set on main memory. It contains a set of Persian sentences. When I search in my memory I get good result, But when I put `ی` or `ک` in my keyword, I don't get a search result.

my search func:

UPDATE:

```
def word_lookup(self,word,ayas):
    pos = []
    return_value = []


try:

    for aya in ayas:

        self.aya_list = aya[3].split()
        word_cnt = 0
        pos = []
        for aya_ in self.aya_list:
            if word in aya_:
                pos.append(word_cnt)
                return_value.append([aya[0],aya[1],aya[2],pos])
            word_cnt += 1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return return_value
```

calling functions

```
word_lookup("my unicode keyword",  a set of ayas)
```

How can I solve it?

I use python3.

Comment: How do you search when you "get good result"? What is "my keyword"? Can you show some code, preferably [example]? With your description, it's like making a phone call to a doctor and saying "guess what's wrong with my nose!"

Comment: Please share some sample code. It will help SO users to debug the issue better.

Comment: I used list and `in` @Amadan

Comment: I update my question.@Amadan @Tajinder

Comment: because `ی` and `ک` have two character-codes. Arabic one and Persian one, take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616063/characters-%D9%8A-and-%DB%8C-and-the-difference-in-persian-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616063/characters-%D9%8A-and-%DB%8C-and-the-difference-in-persian-mysql)

Comment: @PersianGulf  also add a sample input for `word` and `ayas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following patch:

```
if re.match(r'\b\w*ی.*', word):
      word = re.sub(r'ی',r'ﻱ', word)

  if re.match(r'\b\w*ک.*', word):
      word = re.sub(r'ک',r'ﻙ', word)
```